# Communicating with a server on a device using that server as a wifi hotspot

Tags: python, networking, server, ip-address, hotspot

I have some python server code running on a laptop, and am trying to send GET/POST to the server's URL. This works fine using a python client or browser on the laptop, as well as on other devices connected to my home network.

However, I'd like to now use that laptop as a wifi hotspot, and connect to the server using devices that are connecting to that hotspot; for example, connecting to the hotspot on a phone, opening a browser, and entering the IP address and port into the address bar (eg http://192.181.1.XXX:80XX/example).

The URL fails to resolve only on devices using the server as a hotspot; switching back to the normal wifi network without changing the URL then successfully resolves, and a browser on the server itself can access it fine.

Do I need to change the URL in some manner when using the target server as a wifi hotspot, or is there something else I'm missing? Or is this actually impossible due to some networking reasons?

In case it's relevant, here is the server code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json
import cgi
import time
hostName = "192.168.1.XXX"
serverPort = 80XX
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        data = json.dumps({'wifi period': '60', 'poll period': '1', '#':'1'})
        self.wfile.write(bytes(data, "utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        if hasattr(self.headers, 'getheader'):
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            print(ctype)
            if ctype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
                #todo: save file
                return
            if ctype != 'application/json':
                print("invalid ctype.")
                print(ctype)
                self.send_response(400)
                self.end_headers()
                return
            length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
        else:
            header = self.headers.get('content-type')
            if header == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
                length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))
                content = self.rfile.read(length)
                #TODO: save file
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                return
            elif header != 'application/json':
                print(f"Header: {header}")
                self.send_response(400)
                self.end_headers()
                return
            length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))

        # read the message and convert it into a python dictionary
        message = json.loads(self.rfile.read(length))
        print(message)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

Comment: What is the IP address of the server? Also, the cgi module is being deprecated - is there a reason you're not using a framework like Flask, Django or one of the others?

Comment: 192.168.1.XXX is the address (with the XXX changing depending on which device I run the server on- eg 110 or 115).
I don't really have much experience with network or web programming in general, so I have no idea what Flask or Django are for, I'm just adapting what I found in other answers about making a simple webserver in python (which may very well be outdated) as a proof-of-concept to see if everything works together and I can get the project components to communicate arbitrarily before I refactor it (eg for security).